# how to save data through relationship by column value in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am saving data to booking table, and i want to add data to participant table as many times as total_pax are there, the first one in partiipant will be created by my code , now i want to create blank entries for remaining pax inn participant table on basis of total_pax which are in booking

Here is the booking object

```
{"booking":{
    "package_id":4,
    "user_id":1,
    "package_name":"masti maza",
    "first_name":"shubham",
    "last_name":"pradhan",
    "email":"jio@gmail.com",
    "total_pax":"5",
}
```

Now i create Booking

```
 $booking = $request->booking;
            $book = Booking::create($booking);
```

Thereafter i created a single entry in participant table

```
$book->Participants()->create([
                'booking_id' => $book->id,
                'first_name' => $booking['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $booking['last_name'],
                'email' => $booking['email']
            ]);
```

But i also want to create  4 more entries as total_pax in booking request is 5 , one is created ,
but i want to create 4 more entries in participant that will have only booking_id, because others column are nullable

Comment: So use a `for()` loop, and run `$book->Participants()->create(['booking_id' => $book->id])` as many times as is required...

Answer (score 2):

Can you loop through the `total_pax` object like so?

```php
        for ($i = 0; $i < request()->post('total_pax'); $i++) {
            $book->Participants()->create([
                'booking_id' => $book->id,
                'first_name' => ($i === 0) ? $booking['first_name'] : null,
                'last_name'  => ($i === 0) ? $booking['last_name']  : null,
                'email'      => ($i === 0) ? $booking['email']      : null,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: `$i < request()->post('total_pax');` could be `$i < $booking['total_pax'];`, to match the other places you're accessing `$booking[...]`

Comment: $i < $booking['total_pax']-1,thanks , it worked,

Comment: Or `for($i = 1; $i < $booking['total_pax']; $i++)`, etc. (start at 1 instead of 0, so you don't need that `-1`)

Comment: yes, for($i = 1; $i < $booking['total_pax']; $i++), thanks

Comment: is there any better way  other than for loop

Comment: What's wrong with a `for()` loop? Also what does "better" mean in that context? A "proper" way to do this would be to have a `participants: []` array on your `booking` object, each with a `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` property, which you could then do `foreach($booking['participants'] as $participant)`, then `$book->participants()->create($participant)`, but that would require some modifications to however you're sending this `booking` object (HTML Form, AJAX Request, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

use `createMany` instead of `create` and pass multiple modal objects on it